# Create additive index in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame object with multiple variables. I am trying to create an additional variable that represents the number of times that a value (2, for example) occurs in many other variables. For example, if

```
mydata <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, NA), y = c(NA, 2, 2), z=c(NA, NA, 2))
   x  y  z
1  1 NA NA
2  2  2 NA
3 NA  2  2
```

then I want to create a new variable (z1) that represents the number of times that 2 appears in that row, based on variables x and y. So the new data.frame would look like this:

```
   x  y  z z1
1  1 NA NA 0
2  2  2 NA 2
3  NA 2 2  1
```

I've tried using if statements so far, but they return an error because of the missing values. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
mydata$z1 <- apply(X = mydata[,c("x","y")] == 2, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum, na.rm=TRUE)

mydata
   x  y  z z1
1  1 NA NA  0
2  2  2 NA  2
3 NA  2  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
transform(mydata, z1=rowSums(cbind(x,y)==2, na.rm=TRUE))
#   x  y  z z1
#1  1 NA NA  0
#2  2  2 NA  2
#3 NA  2  2  1
```